# Is there any method to store user's last action (i.e. RefreshAll or Refresh)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this set of codes in Class Module to perform some actions after refreshing the Query Tables (1 Query Table in each worksheet). Basically, the macro will replace the hash(#) with dot(.) in the first row of Query Table upon every refresh. I want to add in 1 more parameter to check if user manually clicks "Refresh" or "RefreshAll" button considering 2 scenario below:

1. If user wants to refresh all Query Tables by clicking "RefreshAll" button, the macro should loop through each sheet that contains Query Tables and perform the replace action.
2. If user only wants to refresh 1 particular Query Table by clicking "Refresh" button, the macro should only perform the replace action on that particular sheet.

Current code loops through all sheets containing Query Tables & perform replace action regardless of "RefreshAll" or "Refresh" is clicked..

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyQuery As queryTable

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If Success Then
    
    MsgBox "Query has been refreshed."
    
    ' Declare variables
    Dim myRange As Range, myArr As Variant
    Dim Lastcol As Long, Lastrow As Long, j As Long
    
    ' Find last used range in header row
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim qt As queryTable
    
        'If LastAction = "RefreshAll" Then   'This is the part I want my parameter works like
            For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                For Each qt In WS.QueryTables
                    If Not qt Is Nothing Then
                        WS.Activate
                        ' Assign header row to an array for loop
                        Set myRange = WS.Range("A1", Cells(Lastrow, Lastcol))
                        myArr = myRange
                        
                        ' Loop through the header row and replace "#" with "."
                        For j = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
                            myArr(1, j) = Replace(myArr(1, j), "#", ".")
                        Next j
                        
                        myRange = myArr
                    End If
                Next qt
            Next WS
            
            'LastAction = ""
    
        Else
        
            Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(Lastrow, Lastcol))
            myArr = myRange
            
            ' Loop through the header row and replace "#" with "."
            For j = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
                myArr(1, j) = Replace(myArr(1, j), "#", ".")
            Next j
            
            myRange = myArr
            
        End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub MyQuery_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Refresh query?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Is there a way to check if user clicked "RefreshAll" or "Refresh" button? Alternatively, any other methods to meet the 2 scenarios above?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=QueryTable.AfterRefresh+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to replace the `#` with a `.` within the queries themselves?  You should be able to demote the headers, possibly split the first row from the rest of the data, do your update and stick it back together again.